# Blazor web site shows sometimes Reloading if a user opens the home page

Tags: blazor-server-side, reload

I have a blazor server app that is installed as a windows service and works fine, except after a while that there is not any request from users, and a user wants to open the home page, shows "Reload" event and after a reload continues to work as expected. In this process does not logged any exception or error, and it seems only the connection to the web site has been lost and with reload it refreshes the page.

It happens on FireFox and Edge browsers obviusly more than Chrome, but on Chrome I see it sometimes also.

Any Idea, how can to prevent to show this "Relaod" event? Or what is my mistake?

Comment: You can't avoid the need to reload completely - especially if the browser puts the page to sleep due to inactivity, but you can adjust the [circuit timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0#server-side-circuit-handler-options) and retention - have you looked into that?

Comment: You can also configure [how the client behaves when the circuit is disconnected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0#automatically-refresh-the-page-when-server-side-reconnection-fails)